# How to convert yolov4 weights.wt to pytorch weights .pt?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, yolo

I was trying out the yolov4 from https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/YOLOv4-Cloud-Tutorial and I wanted to convert the weights from .wt files to .pt files for pytorch
Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Pytorch YOLOv4](https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4) (I am biased as I am a maintainer) has the ability to do this with `darknet2pytorch`. The following is an example snippet

```py
from tool.darknet2pytorch import Darknet
WEIGHTS = Darknet(cfgfile)
WEIGHTS.load_weights(weightfile)
```

Where `cfgfile` is your darknet `config.cfg` file, and `weightfile` is your darknet `.wt` weights.

`WEIGHTS` is now an ordinary PyTorch model, which you can save however you'd like.

Comment: getting error as follows:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: Sorry, this is super old and Pytorch YOLOv4 isn't maintained anymore :(